# May I update dataframe row by row index?

Tags: pandas

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    new_row = modify_row(row)
    df[index] = new_row
```

Is there a way to assign a modified row to the original row index without using column name? The above code doesn't seem working, but would be simplest for me if it works.

Comment: You may: `df.loc[index] = new_row`, but generally you shouldn't update rows iteratively, especially with `iterrows`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Python is a pass-by-object-reference programming language, you don't need to modify the original row.

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    modify_row(row)
```

In your original code, you are modifying the dataframe while iterating over it, so it might lead to some unexpected behavior.

Comment: But this only modify row, it doesn't modify df. It needs to be stored back to the df in the original row. You can create an example to test it. The original DF isn't changed at all.

Comment: @marlon As I explained, Python is a pass-by-object-reference programming language, modification to row will applied to the original row in df.

Comment: It doesn't. You have to test it!

Comment: @marlon people wouldn't be able to test it, unless you provide sample data **and** code of `modify_row`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want:

```
df[:] = df.apply(modify_row, axis=1)
```

Comment: My modify has two parameters, one is 'row', and the other one is 'x'. How to pass two parameters in your modify_row function?

Comment: `df.apply(modify_row, x=some_val, axis=1)`.

Comment: But x is the value, not the key. For example, x='30', and my parameters are (row, 30). How to pass them into the modify_row?

Comment: Yes, did you try `df.apply(modify_row, x='30', axis=1)`